# how to send a file through django rest framework's APIRequestFactory when writing test cases?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have built an API in Django Rest Framework (DRF) that takes a file (any file) and a tag (string) as arguments.The API is working fine when tested through Swagger. I am now writing test cases for this API.

The problem is I am not able to send a file through test cases. My test case class inherits 'APITestCase' and I am using DRF's APIRequestFactory to make requests. I went through documentation of APIRequestFactory [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/)  but couldn't find anything useful.

Here is snapshot of the code I am using:

[image: function in my test case class that does the call.].

I debugged and found out there is nothing in request.FILES received in the view on which call was made. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `self.client.post` instead of factory (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient)?

Comment: i tried after you suggested. the **request** object i get from call yields    `<Response status_code=400, "application/json">`  and  request.json() prints `{'detail': 'MultiValueDictKeyError("\'file\'",)'}` . That's because the view is not getting anything with key 'file' perhaps.